# Template for a talk with a column to hold abridged content

Tags: templates, marginpar, notes, columns

I'm looking for either a template (or some pointers to generate one) for using to give talks.

What I'm looking for is something that will allow a column for the 'full' talk, and then a second for notes, such that I can mostly work from the notes, but move back to the relevant point in the richer text should I lose my place.  At the moment I fudge it with margin notes, and wide right margins.

**Edit**
This is for me to give a talk from, not something to display.  I'm after something that will allow me to use shorter notes to talk from, but still give me the fall back of a fuller text.  I guess something like:

```
I want to talk today about the benefits of using version control software, 
such as git, \righthandnote{Benefits of VCS and LaTeX} with talks, and why
pure text based systems such as LaTeX are a natural fit, allowing for easy
text based diffs, patching, etc.  The actual files are also smaller, and 
and mean that entire repositories can be made available fairly easily.  I'm
now going to filler filler filler....
```

The paragraph would be then on the left (1/2-2/3 width), and the \righthandnote would take the rest of the width, and be matched to the paragraph to allow me to see where I should move to, if I've lost the flow of what I was saying.

Does that clarify what I'm after?  It's to help me move away from full talks to notes, but with a fallback position.

Comment: Are you asking about preparing a presentation (e.g. using Beamer), or preparing a "notesheet" that is simply a guide for yourself as you're talking?

Comment: Please add more detail as to your desires. From what you say, a tabular environment with 2 paragraph columns would seem to meet the desiderata, but I rather suspect you've more than that in mind.

Comment: I didn't reread carefully enough after you clarified, and posted a now deleted answer that expanded the right hand margin, the margin paragraphs, and the margin paragraph separation. I now see that's the "fudge" you are currently employing. (Mmm, fudge.) I don't see what's wrong with that solution. What's it missing? If nothing, then why complicate it?

Comment: It might be that marginpar is the best/only solution.  If so, then there's nothing missing per-se.  The resulting 'margin' is a bit odd, but other than that it's just the feeling that there might be a cleaner solution.  And where better to ask the question :)

Comment: In light of your last comment, I am undeleting my answer. Please comment back if you think it was better left deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what you are after. Try this, and season lengths to taste:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=7cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    Some text, else the margin par will be after the lipsum text
    completes.\marginpar{Point the first.}\lipsum[42]

    Text.\marginpar{Point the second.} \lipsum[43]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

Only after posting did I see that this is pretty much what the OP wished to improve upon. Deleted and then restored in light of exchange in the comments.

Comment: that is pretty much what I'm already doing, with margins set to taste!  I guess this is the answer (though I could have put this and claimed the rep :)